# Modify columns width from code android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-tablelayout, layoutparams

I would like to know if there is a way to modify the width of two columns in a table layout (with three columns in total).

The problem is that every column has the same width and a lot of space is wasted because the first two only contain an id and a date meanwhile the last one contains a multiline description.

This is the code in which the table layout is populated:

```
tr_head.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    tr_head.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 230, 230));

    TextView lblSystemStoricalHeaderId = new TextView(this);
    lblSystemStoricalHeaderId.setText("ID      ");

    tr_head.addView(lblSystemStoricalHeaderId);

    TextView lblSystemStoricalHeaderData = new TextView(this);
    lblSystemStoricalHeaderData.setText("Data");

    tr_head.addView(lblSystemStoricalHeaderData);

    TextView lblSystemStoricalHeaderDescription = new TextView(this);
    lblSystemStoricalHeaderDescription.setText("      Descrizione");

    tr_head.addView(lblSystemStoricalHeaderDescription);

    tr_head.setMinimumHeight(30);

    tlSystemStorical.addView(tr_head, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
       LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
           LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    for(int i=0;i<reportList.length;i++){

        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        TextView lblSystemStoricalId = new TextView(this);
        lblSystemStoricalId.setText(""+reportList[i].getId()+"");

        tr.addView(lblSystemStoricalId);

        TextView lblSystemStoricalData = new TextView(this);
        long dataC = reportList[i].getDate()*1000;
        java.util.Date df = new java.util.Date(dataC);
        String vv = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(df);
        lblSystemStoricalData.setText(vv);

        tr.addView(lblSystemStoricalData);

        TableRow.LayoutParams tv3Params = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
        tv3Params.width=0;
        tv3Params.weight=1;
        TextView lblSystemStoricalDescription = new TextView(this);
        lblSystemStoricalDescription.setText(""+reportList[i].getReportDescription());
        lblSystemStoricalDescription.setLayoutParams(tv3Params);

        tr.addView(lblSystemStoricalDescription);

        tr.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);
        tr.setMinimumHeight(40);

        tlSystemStorical.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }
```

and this is the xml file:

```
<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view_system_description"
     >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
         >

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="*"
            android:id="@+id/tl_system_storical"
            >

        </TableLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `width` property to `0` for `TableRow` children, but specify `layout_weight` for them. So you'd write:

```
float[] weights = new float[] { 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.6f};

TextView lblSystemStoricalId = new TextView(this);
lblSystemStoricalId.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, weights[0]))
```

Where `0` is no width for view (because you're using weights), and `weights` array contains weights for your three views.

These weights should sum up to `1`, and each weight is percent of the width that the column should take. So you need to assign weights to your `TableRow` children - `lblSystemStoricalId` would get `weights[0]`, `lblSystemStoricalData` would get `weights[1]` and `lblSystemStoricalDescription` would have `weights[2]`.